# MPMoviePlayerController hide next prev buttons

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

is there an easy (maybe hacky) way to hide the next / prev buttons on apples MPMoviePlayerController?

i dont want to change the skin, just "hide" the skip buttons.

[image]

thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style of the `setControlStyle` property of the *UIMoviePlayerController* instance to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`.

**Edit:**

I guess the best way to get the buttons **exactly** as you want would be to create your own *UIView* subclass that handles the visuals of the controls, implement the buttons that you're after, position them on your custom view, and then position your custom view over your *MPMovieController's* view.

You would then need to hook up the target and actions of your cutom view's buttons to a controller that uses the *[MPMediaPlayback](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback)* functions to control the playback of your *MPMoviePlayerController*.

The work will come in having to create and position your own *UIView* subclass. You should also pay attention to the fact that using this method will not be as efficient as using the built-in controls that you can specify with Apple's `setControlStyle` property.

Comment: i just want to remove the skip buttons, not the complete skin.

Comment: Ohhh...! Try `MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded`?

Comment: thanks but i wanted to have the same skin. just wihtout the buttons :)

Comment: thanks for your effort. well looks like there is no "easy way" to just hide the buttons. i know about the custom player option but the client would never pay for that :)

Comment: There is no such thing as an MPMoviePlayerDelegate protocol. What James most likely wanted to say most likely is that you have to send your control-events (play, pause, stop,...) to the MPMoviePlayerController yourself. In the end, doing what the OP is asking for does indeed demand recreation of the original interface but leaving out certain controls. There is however another way, bad-ass-hacking; go through the subviews of the MPMoviePlayerController.view and hide what you want to be hidden using the hidden-property of the view/control (not recommended but works).

Comment: @Till, sorry yes you're right, what I meant to refer to was the MPMediaPlayback protocol functions (of the MPMoviePlayerController as you suggest). I've edited by post to reflect this. I wouldn't reccomend this hacking approch for two reasons, 1. It's not very maintainable. The code you write will be very hard to read, and if Apple changes the MPMoviePlayerController in an update your app may no longer work for the users. 2. You run the risk that Apple may not allow your app for going against their framework and default user interface.

Comment: But when the 'controlstyle' property is used,an error is shown as :
"Property controlstyle not found as object on MPMovieplayerController".
How to access the controlstyle property ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

[movie.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```