# ios mpmovieplayercontroller disable or not do any action on Previous and Next Button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to disbale or disable its action on the previous and next button of mpMoviePlayerController.[image]

audio is playing from server,its playing fine but when i press previous or next button then it stops playing and never start again this is happening in ios7 only

Comment: more context please...

Comment: @FahimParkar please check this now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430574/mpmovieplayercontroller-hide-next-prev-buttons, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3598383/1066828