# iOS MpMoviePlayerViewController Customization

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController.
I want to disable only next and prev functions.
If you long tap next or prev button, it forward or reward the video.
I want to leave that function and disable only next and prev functions.
If you have done similar before, please advise me

Thank you

Comment: please be careful MPMoviePlayerViewController has been deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: Please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5430645/767329